# AngularJS option selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know there's been a lot of questions for this but I am having the most annoying time figuring out how `AngularJS` handles select option values and which one is selected. I have a simple item which I pass onto a modal window. This item contains `template_id`. I also have `templates` which have a name and an id and I wish to create a simple select where the option which  has the value of the item's template_id gets selected:

```
<select name="templateId">
  <option value="8000">name</option>
  <option value="8001" selected>name 2</option>
</select>
```

Now with AngularJS I do this:

```
<select name="templateId"
    ng-model="domain.templateId"
    ng-options="t.template_id as t.name for t 
                in templates track by t.template_id">
      <option value="">Choose template</option>
 </select>
```

In the controller I set the 'selected' value with:

```
Data.get('templates').then(function(result) {
    $scope.templates = result;
});

$scope.domain = {
    template_id: item.template_id,
    templateId: { template_id: item.template_id }
};
```

I have actually gotten to a point where I can send the template_id to the REST API and the response there reads

```
template_id: 8000
```

However, there is some minor annoying behaviour in the select element. I get the item I want selected, but when I attempt to select another option it switches the selected to the pre-set 'Choose template' option but the value or rather the 'real selected item' is still the original "selected" value I set in the controller. I can see it in the REST API response. This is not however what I selected. After this initial bug it continues to work as it's supposed to but how can I get rid of this?

Comment: Instead of templateId: { template_id: item.template_id } do templateId: item.template_id

Comment: Doesnt work. It wont set the selected value.

Comment: ng-selected maybe !?! https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

Comment: ng-selected does nothing. Tried ng-selected="domain.template_id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a example to solve your issue.

```js
angular.module('app.select', [])
  .controller('SelecetCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.templates = [{
      template_id: 1,
      name: 'tst1'
    }, {
      template_id: 2,
      name: 'tst2'
    }, {
      template_id: 3,
      name: 'tst3'
    }];

    $scope.selected = {
      template: {
        template_id: 2
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app.select'>
  <div ng-controller='SelecetCtrl'>
    <select name="templateId" ng-model="selected.template" 
            ng-options="t as t.name for t 
                in templates track by t.template_id">
      <option value="">Choose template</option>
    </select> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well the answer was there, just not so visible. Had to remove t.id and just leave it as t. Otherwise your example is almost identical to my code, you just created the selected outside the $scope.domain